# Loading database file from network path in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, air

I'm making a project in adobe air about saving patients data and all their records in a dental center, I want to make the database on the main computer and the other computers on the same network when first open the program asks about the path of the database and open it and save it's location, and when i open the program second time it opens the database over the network automatically without asking about the path. 
I tried to save the path in a shared object but it did not work any ideas guys?
sorry I did not post the code here it is (the code here is working now i was using fileReference but now am using file class and it works like magic but i want to ask if I made changes from one computer will it be saved if the database was opened with multiple computers?):

```
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.data.SQLConnection;
import flash.data.SQLStatement;
import flash.data.SQLResult;
import flash.data.SQLSchema;
import flash.errors.SQLError;
import flash.events.SQLErrorEvent;
import flash.events.SQLEvent;
import flash.data.SQLMode;


var myDatabase: File = new File();
var dbFilter: FileFilter = new FileFilter("Database", "*.db");
var connection: SQLConnection = new SQLConnection();
var setting: SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("shardd");
if (setting.data.firstRun == undefined) {
    setting.data.firstRun = 0;
    trace("First Run");
    chooseDatabaseLocation();
} else {
    trace("Not First Run");
    //setting.data.firstRun = 0;
    myDatabase.nativePath = setting.data.databaseFile;
    openDatabase();
}

function chooseDatabaseLocation() {
    myDatabase.browseForOpen("Open Database", [dbFilter]);
    myDatabase.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, databaseSelected)
}

function databaseSelected(Event) {
    trace("databaseSelected");
    setting.data.databaseFile = myDatabase.nativePath;
    openDatabase();

}
function openDatabase() {
    trace("openDatabase: "+myDatabase.nativePath);
    connection = new SQLConnection();
    connection.addEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN, loadInfo);
    connection.openAsync(myDatabase, SQLMode.UPDATE);
}


function loadInfo(SQLEvent):void
{
    trace("loadInfo");
    var stat:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stat.sqlConnection = connection;
    stat.text = "SELECT id, direct FROM general_info WHERE id=1";
    stat.execute(-1, new Responder(showInfo));
}

function showInfo(evt:SQLResult){
    trace("showInfo");
    if (evt.data != null)
    {
        direct_txt.text = evt.data[0].direct;
    }else{
        direct_txt.text = "No data";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well show us what you've done, what errors you had.. Anything! We're not magicians to just say "this is the answer"!

Comment: Try to use a [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) object, it can easily to the job.

Comment: thank you for your comments i managed to solve it with file class but need to try it to see if it save on multiple computers

Comment: Why aren't you using regular form submissions to php?  It's the best design - keep the backend encapsulated.  Among all the other reasons, you see you'll have to update the air app every time you change anything on the backend or the connection instead of just the php.

Comment: well i wanted to try that but it has 2 disadvantages the first one it should be online while the network am working on is offline, and when I use php offline i need to install mySQL server which i don't because it will be complicated install and i want it very simple